# Nucleon resonance

Tags: particle-physics, quarks, baryons

I tried to fit low baryon resonances to N(1440) in an SU(3) octet.

So I started with

$$\frac{N + \Xi}{2} = \frac{3 \Lambda + \Sigma}{4}$$

What should  the respective  $\Lambda (I=0), \Xi(I=\frac{1}{2}), \Sigma(I=1)$ be identified with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PDG [resonance listing](https://pdg.lbl.gov/2020/tables/rpp2020-qtab-baryons.pdf) to fish from for a lowest resonance baryon octet with 1/2+ visibly suggests

N(1440) ; Λ(1600) ; Σ(1660) ;  Ξ(1690) ,

but, beware!, the cascade concluding the above list  has not had its spin-parity fully identified.

Still, slipping in a strange quark crudely raises the energy by about 100 MeV as it is expected to, and the
Gell-Mann--Okubo sum/difference you appear to be relying on (but why?), in MeVs, seems to zero out adequately,
$$
2(1440+1690) -3(1600) -1660 \approx -200.
$$

Comment: I used formula, because I wanted to check accuracy of linear Gell-Mann-Okubo relation for baryons, firstly matching octet to N(1440) with spin $J =1/2$ and parity $P = 1^+$.

Comment: After the advent of quark models and QCD simulations, the G-M--O formula is somewhat "academic", however, no?